# $P(\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k <(1-\varepsilon)\log n)=0$ if $Y_n=\min_{1\le k\le n}X_k$ where $X_n$, $n\ge 1$ are i.i.d. Unif$(0,1)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

$$P\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k <(1-\varepsilon)\log n\right\}=0\quad\text{if}\quad Y_n=\min_{1\le k\le n}X_k$$
where $X_n$, $n\ge 1$ are i.i.d. Unif$(0,1)$.

The original question was to show $\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k/\log n$ goes to $1$ in probability. I've shown the other way but for this direction, I keep getting the value $1$ instead of $0$ as the limit.

\begin{align*}P\left\{\sum Y_k <(1-\varepsilon)\log (n)\right\}
&=P\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n X_{(1)} <(1-\varepsilon)\log (n)\right\}\\
&=P\left\{X_{(1)}<\frac{(1-\varepsilon)\log (n)}{n}\right\}\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{(1-\varepsilon)\log n}{n}\right)^n\\
&\rightarrow 1-e^{-(1-\varepsilon)\log n}\\
&\rightarrow1\quad\text{ as }n\to\infty,
\end{align*}

but I need this to be $0$. Does $\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k=\sum_{k=1}^n \min_{1\le j\le k} X_k=nX_{(1)}$?

Comment: Of course your final question has a negative answer, $\{X_2 < X_1\}$ happens with positive probability.

Comment: How can I simplify $\sum_{k=1}^n \min_{1\le j\le k}X_k$?

Comment: see my answer below; you need to start by copying the question out correctly...

Comment: The question was to show $\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k/\log n$ goes to 1 in probability. I showed that $P(\sum Y_k > (1+\varepsilon) \log n)$ goes to 0 so this was the other term.

Answer (score 1):

Your question as stated can't possibly be true. You need some sort of limiting statement in $n$. For instance, taking $n = 2$ (as we may: you haven't put any limits in; you apparently claim the probability is zero for all natural numbers) and taking $\varepsilon = 2$ the probability is clearly positive:

\begin{align*}
P\left\{Y_1 + Y_2 < \frac{1}{2}\log(2)\right\} &\geq P\left\{X_1 \in \left(0,\frac{1}{4}\log(2)\right), X_2 \in \left(\frac{1}{4}\log(2),\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\right)\right\}\\
& = \frac{1}{16}\log^2(2)\\
&> 0.
\end{align*}